# Handling complex pipe delimited CSV/Flat file imports in Python using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I've hunted around on stackoverflow but can't find a similar problem - sorry in advance if this exists.

I'm trying to import a large "|" separated CSV file with 7 columns.

The issue is that some of the data columns contain free text, which in some cases also happens to contain additional pipes. This causes it to error on hundreds of rows as it is naturally expecting, in my case 7 columns, but it is seeing 8, 9, 10 rows.

The code below will skip the unusual rows and import the rest of the file, but this doesn't help as we need all of the rows.

```
import pandas as pd
fileImport = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', sep="|", error_bad_lines=False, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

Is there an obvious trick for handling these unusual/annoying rows?

An example of such a row:

```
11111|2222|2000-11-01 00:00:00|AAAA.|Alcohol use disorder identificatn test|XXXXXX||An overall total score of less than 5 is negative||How often: Monthly or less||How many: 3 - 4||6 or more units: Never||Date: Unknown|||
```

It seems that separate items of data within the column are further encapsulated with pipes:

```
|An overall total score of less than 5 is negative||How often: Monthly or less||How many: 3 - 4||6 or more units: Never||Date: Unknown|
```

Comment: Could you share an example of a such rows?

Comment: I've added an example to the main question above in code tags to make it more readable.

Comment: And what is the header row? Are you sure it is a well-formatted file (each row has the same number of columns, even though some values are missing)?

Comment: Other than these odd rows where there is a text dump with pipes in the text the file is formatted perfectly. Every other row where this text problem doesn't occur processes in as it should. I'm just unsure whether there is a way to handle these additional pipes that occur in some way.

Comment: Unless the text is wrapped in quotation marks, I don't think there is a way for panads to understand what's text and what's separators (personally I don't understand by looking at it).